# MSYS2 undefined reference to _imp__XXXXXXXX

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, ld, msys2

I am trying to compile a fairly simple library using MSYS2, but I get some strange undefined reference errors, even though the functions are contained within the files I am compiling.
Relevant portion of Makefile:

```
luars232.dll: librs232_windows.o librs232.o luars232.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o luars232.dll luars232.o librs232.o librs232_windows.o -L./lua-5.1.5/src/ -llua

luars232.o: librs232/bindings/lua/luars232.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) librs232/bindings/lua/luars232.c -o luars232.o

librs232.o: librs232/src/rs232.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) librs232/src/rs232.c -o librs232.o

librs232_windows.o: librs232/src/rs232_windows.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) librs232/src/rs232_windows.c -o librs232_windows.o
```

The first few lines of compilation output:

```
$ make windows
cc -c -fPIC -I librs232/include/ -I/usr/include/lua5.1/ -I/usr/include/json -I./lua-5.1.5/src/ -DWIN32 librs232/src/rs232_windows.c -o librs232_windows.o
cc -c -fPIC -I librs232/include/ -I/usr/include/lua5.1/ -I/usr/include/json -I./lua-5.1.5/src/ -DWIN32 librs232/src/rs232.c -o librs232.o
cc -c -fPIC -I librs232/include/ -I/usr/include/lua5.1/ -I/usr/include/json -I./lua-5.1.5/src/ -DWIN32 librs232/bindings/lua/luars232.c -o luars232.o
cc -shared -DWIN32 -o luars232.dll luars232.o librs232.o librs232_windows.o -L./lua-5.1.5/src/ -llua
C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: luars232.o:luars232.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `_imp__rs232_init'
C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: luars232.o:luars232.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `_imp__rs232_set_device'
C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: luars232.o:luars232.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `_imp__rs232_open'
C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: luars232.o:luars232.c:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `_imp__rs232_close'
```

And an excerpt from rs232_windows.c to show that the function it is looking for is actually defined in the source code:

```
RS232_LIB struct rs232_port_t *
rs232_init(void)
{
    struct rs232_port_t *p = NULL;
    struct rs232_windows_t *wx = NULL;
    p = (struct rs232_port_t *) malloc(sizeof(struct rs232_port_t));
```

Does anyone know why the compiler can not find these functions within the source code?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after many hours of trial and error, this problem is caused by the source files assuming MSVC as the compiler (instead of gcc as used by MSYS2) and adding __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport) modifiers to the function definitions.